# Swap array values at specific indices?

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa

I'm creating asynchronous `NSURLConnections` for images based off of an array of dictionaries, each with their own image URL:

```
var posts = [
    ["url": "url0", "calledIndex": 0],
    ["url": "url1", "calledIndex": 1],
    ["url": "url2", "calledIndex": 2],
    ["url": "url3", "calledIndex": 3]
]
```

Given the asynchronous nature of the connections (which is what I want, fastest images load first), the images might load in a different order, such as:

```
url0
url2
url3
url1
```

If the images are loaded out of order, however, the original `posts` array needs to be reorganized according to when the images loaded. So, given the above example, `posts` should now look like:

```
var posts = [
    ["url": "url0", "calledIndex": 0],
    ["url": "url2", "calledIndex": 2],
    ["url": "url3", "calledIndex": 3],
    ["url": "url1", "calledIndex": 1]
]
```

Is there any way in Swift to swap values of an array at a specific index with values from the same array at a different index? I first attempted this by using the `swap` function:

```
// Index the images load
var loadedIndex = 0

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

    // Index of the called image in posts
    let calledIndex = posts["calledIndex"] as! Int

    // Index that the image actually loaded
    let loadedIndex = loadedIndex

    // If the indicies are the same, the image is already in the correct position
    if loadedIndex != calledIndex {

        // If they're not the same, swap them
        swap(&posts[calledIndex], &posts[loadedIndex])
    }
}
```

I then attempted something similar without the `swap` function:

```
// The post that was actually loaded
let loadedPost = posts[calledIndex]

// The post at the correct index
let postAtCorrectIndex = posts[loadedIndex]

posts[calledIndex] = postAtCorrectIndex
posts[loadedIndex] = loadedPost
```

In both scenarios, however, the array values are not correctly swapped. I realize this is a logic error, but I'm failing to see where the error actually lies.

As far as I can tell, it's swapping correctly the first time, but then the new dictionary has an incorrect `calledIndex` value, causing it swap back to its original position.

This hypothesis might be completely wrong, and I realize I'm having a difficult time describing the situation, but I will attempt to provide as much clarification as possible.

---

I made a test case, you can [download the source code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0odu5t24mx40h16/Test.zip?dl=0). The code for it is:

```
var allPosts:Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> = [
    ["imageURL": "http://i.imgur.com/aLsnGqn.jpg", "postTitle":"0"],
    ["imageURL": "http://i.imgur.com/vgTXEYY.png", "postTitle":"1"],
    ["imageURL": "http://i.imgur.com/OXzDEA6.jpg", "postTitle":"2"],
    ["imageURL": "http://i.imgur.com/ilOKOx5.jpg", "postTitle":"3"],
]

var lastIndex = 0
var threshold = 4
var activeConnections = Dictionary<NSURLConnection, Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>>()

func loadBatchInForwardDirection(){
    func createConnection(i: Int){
        allPosts[i]["calledIndex"] = i
        var post = allPosts[i]
        let imageURL = NSURL(string: post["imageURL"] as! String)
        if imageURL != nil {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: imageURL!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
            let connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
            if connection != nil {
                activeConnections[connection!] = post
            }
        }
    }
    let startingIndex = lastIndex;
    for (var i = startingIndex; i < startingIndex + threshold; i++){
        createConnection(i)
        lastIndex++
    }
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    if activeConnections[connection] != nil {
        let dataDict = activeConnections[connection]!["data"]
        if dataDict == nil {
            activeConnections[connection]!["data"] = NSMutableData(data: data)
        } else {
            (activeConnections[connection]!["data"] as! NSMutableData).appendData(data)
        }
    }
}

var loadedIndex = 0
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
    let loadedPost = activeConnections[connection]!
    activeConnections.removeValueForKey(connection)
    let data = loadedPost["data"] as? NSData
    let calledIndex = loadedPost["calledIndex"] as! Int
    println(calledIndex)

    swap(&allPosts[calledIndex], &allPosts[loadedIndex])
    //(allPosts[calledIndex], allPosts[loadedIndex]) = (allPosts[loadedIndex], allPosts[calledIndex])

    loadedIndex++
    done(loadedIndex)
}

func done(index: Int){
    if index == 4 {
        println()
        println("Actual: ")
        println(allPosts[0]["postTitle"] as! String)
        println(allPosts[1]["postTitle"] as! String)
        println(allPosts[2]["postTitle"] as! String)
        println(allPosts[3]["postTitle"] as! String)
    }
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    loadBatchInForwardDirection()
    println("Loaded: ")
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```

The output is:

> Loaded: 
>   1
>   0
>   2
>   3
>
> Actual: 
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3

However the expected, "Actual" output should be:

> 1 0 2 3

It's worth noting that using the tuples code results in slightly wonky results, but nothing that matches the actual order. You can see what I mean by uncommenting that line.

Comment: Your `posts` definition isn't legal Swift. Is this your actual code? What problem are you seeing? Is `posts` really an Swift `Array`, or is it an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` defined some other way?

Comment: @RobNapier whoops, I simplified the array down but forgot the quotes around the key. I'm going to write a test case that hopefully shows the problem, and I'll post it when I'm done.

Comment: Why don't you just sort by specifying a closure to use for comparisons?

Comment: @RobNapier Updated the post with an example test case. I'm probably missing something stupid, but it has become one of those problems I've been staring at for too long and nothing is helping!

Comment: @neo Is that any better than using `swap` or Rob's tuples code?

Comment: It does what you want. And basically what you want is to sort. Instead of writing your own sort and get into confusion like you are in now, just use built in sort.

Comment: @neo one potential problem, however, is that the array generally has thousands of values in it, but only a certain portion of that array should be sorted. For instance, instead of sorting items 0...999, it should only sort items 4...7.

Comment: I understand your concern, but most sort algorithms are very efficient on already sorted lists. I don't know what sorting algorithm Apple's sorted function uses, but I don't think they would choose something inefficient. With your swapping, you try to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @neo But the majority of the items don't have their calledIndex key yet because they haven't been loaded yet

Comment: Then sort once you get all items have their calledIndex populated.

Comment: @neo Can't, since the value is populated when an image loads, and it would make zero sense to load every single image and then sort.

Comment: You never increment the loadedIndex variable in your first attempt code sample.

Comment: @neo I apologize, I was just trying to show the structure of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually ended up being much easier than expected. Since the currently loaded post is being held in `activeConnections`, I can simply replace the `allPosts` value at the loaded index with the currently loaded post:

```
allPosts[loadedIndex] = loadedPost
```

I can't think of any downsides to this method, but if anyone thinks of any, please let me know.

Answer (score 14):

You can just assign via tuples:

```
var xs = [1,2,3]   
(xs[1], xs[2]) = (xs[2], xs[1])
```

But what problem are you actually having with `swap`? The following should work fine:

```
swap(&xs[1], &xs[2])
```

Comment: I updated the question with a test case. The only difference between the download and the snippet below is that the array no longer has the `calledIndex` key hardcoded.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the changeIndex's value type to String, then below code should work

```
var posts = [
    ["url": "url0", "calledIndex": "0"],
    ["url": "url2", "calledIndex": "2"],
    ["url": "url3", "calledIndex": "3"],
    ["url": "url1", "calledIndex": "1"]
]

posts = sorted(posts, { (s1: [String:String], s2: [String:String]) -> Bool in
    return s1["calledIndex"] < s2["calledIndex"]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use sort on the calledIndex value:

```
var posts = [
  ["url": "url0", "calledIndex": 0],
  ["url": "url2", "calledIndex": 2],
  ["url": "url1", "calledIndex": 1],
  ["url": "url3", "calledIndex": 3]
]


var sortedPosts = sorted(posts) { ($0["calledIndex"] as! Int) < ($1["calledIndex"] as! Int)}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, only sections of the array will have the calledIndex variable specified, however.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that swapping the values doesn't give you the right order, as you may swap an already swapped value. As an example, if you receive in the order 3,0,1,2, then you'll swap:

```
array_before   called_index   loaded_index   array_after
0, 1, 2, 3     0              3              3, 1, 2, 0
3, 1, 2, 0     1              0              1, 3, 2, 0
1, 3, 2, 0     2              1              1, 2, 3, 0
1, 2, 3, 0     3              2              1, 2, 0, 3
```

So this will give you 1,2,0,3 even though you received (and correctly swapped) 3,0,1,2.

If you want the swapping to work you'll have to keep track of what's been swapped so you know which index to swap into. It's probably going to be easier to add to a new array as you get the data back, or to add a new field to storing the loaded index and sort on that at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

### In Swift 4

```
  array.swapAt(i, j)  // will swap elements at i and j
```

---

### Protocol

```
protocol MutableCollection {
  /// Exchange the values at indices `i` and `j`.
  ///
  /// Has no effect when `i` and `j` are equal.
  public mutating func swapAt(_ i: Index, _ j: Index)
}
```

See [SE-0173 Add MutableCollection.swapAt(*:*:)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0173-swap-indices.md) for more information about swapAt.